# PyQt6: How can I fetch position of mouse pointer from QGraphicsScene and use the variables in the other class?

Tags: python, oop, mousemove, qgraphicsscene, pyqt6

I'm new to pyqt6 and even to python. As the title indicates, I got stuck with handling mouse position variables. I was expecting to show coodinates of mouse pointer in the `QLabel`  correspond to the mouse movement. I was able to fetch coordinates from `mouseMoveEvent` in the `QGraphicsScene` class to `getPosition` in the `Window` class. But, that coodinates couldn't be passed to the other function in `Window` class.

Here is my code so far.

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel

class GraphicsScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.posX = event.scenePos().x()
        Window.getPosition(Window, event.scenePos().x())

class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        scene = GraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(scene)

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.Layout = QVBoxLayout() 
        self.gw = GraphicsView() # an image is meant to be set here.
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.gw)
        self.label = QLabel("Coordinate: x") # wanna show coorinates here correspond to the mouse movement. 
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.Layout) 

    def getPosition(self, posX):
        self.label.setText("Coordinate: x" + str(self.posX))
        self.repaint()
        print(posX)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

and got an ERROR like this:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Window' has no attribute 'label'
```

It seemas the `self` in the `getPosition` function is set to `GraphicsScene` class after being called (unexpectedly for me). And I have no idea this approach works or not after reading several web documents and asking help for chatGPT. Possibly, I took wrong approach to layout of Widgets.

Any suggestion would be helpful because I'm stuck whole this week with dipression.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using class `Window` as parameter to `setPosition` was wrong, one needs to use an instance of this class. I did this by climbing up the `parent()` methods and there may be prettier ways to achieve the same. However, it works for now and I did not want to throw in too many changes.

I marked notable changes with comments.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets

class GraphicsScene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.posX = event.scenePos().x()
        self.parent().parent().setPosition(event.scenePos().x()) # <-- crawl up the ancestry


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        scene = GraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(scene)


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.Layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.gw = GraphicsView(self) # <-- pass self here
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.gw)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Coordinate: x") # wanna show coorinates here correspond to the mouse movement.
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(self.Layout)

    def setPosition(self, posX): # <-- this is a setter, not a getter
        self.label.setText("Coordinate: x" + str(posX)) # <-- use argument posX
        self.repaint()
        print(posX)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a million Friedrich. The crawling up approach using `parent()` methods totally makes sense for me. Also the function name `setPosition` instead of `getPosition` does.

Comment: Glad I could help. Personally, I don't like "train wrecks" like `parent().parent().etc` and I see there are several member variables which could be local variables instead. You might consider to visit [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and get some suggestions on how to improve it. As they say: make it work, then make it pretty.